# Put input submit on same line as input box

Tags: html, css

This is probably simple but I dont know how to do it. Currently with this code the "find" button sits on the line below the input "location" box. How do I get it to sit on the same line to the right like most search boxes work?

**HTML**

```
<div class="fieldwrapper">
<input id="field_location" class="field r2" placeholder="Town, City or Postcode" id="Postcode" name="Postcode" type="text" value=""><input type="submit" id="findbutton" value="Find" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
field { font-family:arial, sans-serif; border-color: #d9d9d9; border-top:solid 1px #c0c0c0; }
input.field{width:100%}
```

**Link**
http://jsfiddle.net/VL3Dj/

Comment: it would be great if you would put this code in http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net so others can start fixing your code right in place

Comment: Ok! http://jsfiddle.net/VL3Dj/

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you want your text box to be `100% width` and a button besides it you can do it like this : [**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CQEAd/)

```
<input type="submit"value="Find" style="float: right" />
<div style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: .5em;">
   <input type="text" style="width: 100%;" />
</div>​
```

Comment: This is the answer I am looking for. Thank you. I cant mark as answer for 5 mins though.

Comment: I have struggled with this for years. Can anyone explain why the overflow: hidden makes it work and why it doesn't work without it?

Comment: @KevinLawrence, adding overflow:hidden (or any other value besides visible) creates a new [Block Formatting Context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context). This changes the way the div calculates it's width to consider the floated element before it.

Answer (score 9):

............***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/e94q3/12/)***

Hi now add this css

```
.fieldwrapper{
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

***[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/e94q3/12/)***

Answer (score 3):

You only need to know the width of the button for it to work. Then you basically give the input a full width and position absolute the button to the right. The padding is so no text sits behind the button:

```
    <form method="post" action="">
      <input type="text" name="search-str" id="search-str" value=""/>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

As for the CSS:

```
form {
  position: relative;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

button {
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because your input field is set to be 100% wide, leaving no space for the button beside it.

Here is a a fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/ThfES/1/

Comment: I guess he needs text field 100%

Comment: @Alien Maybe he does - mine is just one of dozens of possible suggestions.  If he prefers your solution then I'm sure he'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Yeah I want the text field 100%, sorry.

Comment: @James No need to apologise.  There are some ideas here that'll work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `float` block elements so they appear side-by-side, so to speak. `inline` elements like `<a>` and `<span>` do this by default. Learn more about the CSS Box model.

Your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/HBJtT/

EDIT: Keeping `input` field as `100%` wide.

Potential solution: http://jsfiddle.net/3TZL8/

I do not support this solution though, if your motivation for keeping the input text field `100%` wide is so that the button and the field look "seamlessly together", you should use a grid or a UI framework. I like Foundation framework, a possible solution can be seen here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/forms.php (Scroll down to "Input with a postfix action" example)

Comment: Please see the edit. I'm not sure why you want to keep the input element 100% wide, can you please elaborate? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try following, width:50%

```
input.field{width:50%}​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this ( worked in my case ):

```
<div style="width:150px"><p>Start: <input  type="text" id="your_id"></p> 
  </div>

<div style="width:130px;margin-left: 160px;margin-top: -52px">
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-mini="true">Button</a>
</div>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gn3qx6w6/1/